# Offset top jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('a').on('click', function() { // Au clic sur un élément
    var speed = 750; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $('.section').offset().top }, speed );
    return false;
});
```

How can I set a custom offset value in pixels?

Comment: What do you mean set a custom offset? Just set a number instead of reading it?

Comment: Try `$( ".section" ).offset({ top: 10});`, here 10 is value in pixel. Check [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for more details.

Comment: @dhn please don't create snippets unless they actually *do* something. Converting bare JavaScript to a JS-only snippet, with no HTML on which to operate, is not an improvement. And if you're going to edit at all, please fix *everything* you can find - remove "Thanks", fix punctuation, etc... ["Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this:

```
let myTop = 100;
$('a').on('click', function() { // Au clic sur un élément
    let speed = 750; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: myTop + "px" }, speed );
    return false;
});
```